# HighStock Boost module Chrome browser error

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I want to load many stock charts on a single page. ~1500 charts with 1 year timeseries data.

I use the boost module but get the following error on Chrome Console and midway the Chrome goes to a black screen, however it recovers from it yet the error persists

```
when compiling fragment shader:

highstock.js:473 [highcharts boost] - unable to init WebGL renderer
highstock.js:473 [highcharts boost] shader error - when compiling vertex shader:
```

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Hi @user4772933, Creating ~1500 charts on a single page may be too heavy. Have you considered for example loading only these charts which are visible in a current viewport?

Comment: Can you please give me an example? How to do this, also how would it work with finding the chart? If I want to search for lets say some chart which is not currently in the visible port. Would it work ?

Comment: Hello, Sure, I mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6fvyxj72/ You can create only empty containers with some data attribute used for searching.